# selectbox issue when typing

Tags: angularjs

see [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xaJg397zdI3iMm6Nv64I?p=preview) to reproduce issue.

```
see plunker for code
```

[image]

Any help would be great!

-trav.

Comment: where is the problem? it works for me in chrome latest.

Comment: Hi Rabi, i have added a pic which shows what i get in chrome (latest) , after typing 'ADL' it shows 'ABX' as selected.  Are you sure you typed in 'ADL' and not selected it with mouse?

Comment: working fine with chrome latest